# Set different exception on exchange at the processor

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route like that :

```
onException(classOf[RuntimeException]).process(runtimeProcessor).process(doSmth).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "new", "${exchangeId} --- ${exception.stacktrace} ")
```

On the processor I do :

```
 CustomException customException =new CustomException () 
    exchange.setException(customException ) 
    exchange.getOut.setBody(doc)
```

The issue now that after this processor , it doesn't go to other processors (i.e. in my case , it doesn't go to "doSmth" processor )

I guess that behavior is that I have changed the exception on the exchange that I have built my "onException" over it .

Is there any way to force to go on my route even after changing the Exchange's exception !!

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly...also, post questions on either Camel-Users forum or here...not both

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to wrap the caught exception that comes into the exchage and wrap it into another custom exception .

After this wrapping I need to set this exception into a custom exchange .
I have discoverd later from @Claus Ibsen-2 on the camel forum that Camel won't cont. routing when I use

```
exchange.setException(ex)
```

I have managed to do some work around by doing the following @ processor :

```
exchange.getOut.setHeader("ex",customException)
```

then @Route :

```
this.onException(classOf[IOException]).process(doSmth).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "new", ${in.header.ex} ")
```

It prints into my log the following and that what I exactly need from the beginning : 
CustomException: java.lang.IOException